# Tfs automated release at which step tokenization evaluated

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, automated-deployment

I have three different environment QA and PreProd and Prod.
My question is
I have particular build# deployed on QA and PreProd and just before promoting the same for Prod we updated some Prod environment variable value(this variable replaces tokenized value in appconfig.json file and is different for each environment).
In this case will promoting the same Release for Prod will pick the new value or I need to create new Release from QA environment and then promote to next steps.

Comment: Do you have questions related to this thread?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add new [Stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) for each environment in the same release pipeline, then in each stage, you could add task to do tokenization.

For example:
[File transforms and variable substitution reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic)

[Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)